# How to turn off hyperthreading on hp z230 Win7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, cpu, performance-tuning, hyper-threading

I have a legacy application that when ported to this new HP desktop exhibits performance errors.  I need to disable hyper-threading on this desktop.  It has an Intel I5-4095 quad core processor.  The BIOS that I'm getting into actually seems like some sort of set up tool.  There are no processor or performance selections,  I don't think I'm really in BIOS.  I pressed F2 on boot up and tried again using F10.  similar results

Thank You

Comment: Does the problem resolve if you assign core affinity to the process in Task Manager? You may need to repeat this process every run but it could be a proof of concept.

Comment: What led you to believe that hyper-threading is the issue?

Comment: What's the model of HP desktop that you're using?

Comment: HP z230 with I5-4095 processor.    I'm in the process of elimination.  hyper-threading was on my list.   My app, written in 1999, has some time critical functionality.  when a process or thread is bounced to another core the timing is messed up.  I think its because the cores each have their own time reference and thus are not the same

Comment: As far as affinity goes...... when I start the app I use this script                 cmd.exe /c start   "appname" /affinity3 "appname.exe"            Hopefully that sthe app the same affinity number every time that I start it

Comment: If your app has issues like that you should probably use /affinity 1.